# AzureStorage Table Query: Building a Contains Filter

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, string-comparison

I'm aware that Azure Storage doesn't have a contains like filter in their current API. However, I also know that you can build a contains like filter for strings using code like the following:

```
            TableQuery<TableEntity> Query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>()
            .Where(
            TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, substring),
                TableOperators.And,
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, substring + someValue)
                ));
```

My Question is what should I use as someValue to make this equivalent to a contains?

I can't seem to find a chart online that indicates what char is the first char for all chars lexigraphically for c#. Is there any reason not to do this, and do the search on the client side? My partitionKey is well defined subgroups.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually uses the `ascii` order to compare in the filter.

For example, if the `substring` is `good`, then in the second filter:

`TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, "good" + someValue)`,

you should change it to

```
TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, "gooe")
```

There is no need to add `someValue`. Just replace the last char for your substring, to the next ascii char.

Comment: So something like this shoould work right? TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, substring.Remove(substring.Length - 1, 1) + (char)(((int)substring.Last()) + 1));